# if cells ("D(j):H(j)") have only value 0 then delete rows

Tags: excel, vba

can someone help me with that? In column C, individual cells are initially empty, and the code works in the section. In the sections where there are several empty cells in column C, the code does not work. What exactly do I have to change regarding "lastrow2" or at an other position of the code to achieve the desired goal?

```
lastrow2 = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

For j = lastrow2 To 1 Step -1
    If (Cells(j, 4) = 0 And Cells(j, 5) = 0 And Cells(j, 6) = 0 And Cells(j, 7) = 0 And Cells(j, 8) = 0 And Cells(j, 9) = 0) Then
        Rows(j).Delete
    End If
Next j
```

Would be very grateful for your support. :)

Best regards,
Bamane

Comment: Are these columns definitely numeric? Perhaps also check for "" (empty string)?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you describe "does not work" in more details?

Comment: @MiguelH I use the following code to put in some Null:         

For k = 2 To lastrow3  
            Set Myrange = Range(Cells(k,4),Cells(k,32)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) Myrange.Formula = "0"
Next k

Comment: @MathieuGuindon the code stopps wokring when the section in C starts where are some cells empty.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the exact error message you're getting, if you're getting an error (which is still unclear) - see [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Testing column **C** may be too shallow.  This:

```
Sub trewq()
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    lastrow2 = r.Rows.Count + r.Row - 1

    For j = lastrow2 To 1 Step -1
        If (Cells(j, 4) = 0 And Cells(j, 5) = 0 And Cells(j, 6) = 0 And Cells(j, 7) = 0 And Cells(j, 8) = 0 And Cells(j, 9) = 0) Then
            Rows(j).Delete
        End If
    Next j
End Sub
```

may be better..................we are checking columns **D** through **I**

Comment: thank you a lot. This code is working pretty good and fast. You saved my weekend :)

Comment: can you say me how I can understand the first three lines in the code? Cause I saw this often but I don't know how to use it and in which case this makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking that each cell = 0, why not use a couple of formulas?

```
Sub DeleteRowsWithZero()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim j As Long
    For j = lastrow To 1 Step -1
        If WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("D" & j & ":I" & j)) = 0 And _
           WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("D" & j & ":I" & j), "*") = 0 Then
            Rows(j).Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

`WorksheetFunction.Sum()` checks that all the cells in your test range have a value of 0.

But if some of those cells have a text value rather than a numeric value, you'll still get 0, so we then use `WorksheetFunction.CountIf()` to test that none of those cells contain text (by checking against the wildcard "*").

If both checks = 0, then we can delete the row.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, this is also working quite good :)
Can you please explain me how to use or understand Range("D" & j & ":I" & j) ? Because I see diffrent kind of using this function. Like Range(A:A & lastrow)...
I would like to understand this cause I'm interested in VBA.

Comment: You can refer to a range of cells using A1-style references by writing `Range("startcell:endcell")`. e.g.: `Range("A1:D7")` to select the intersection of the first four colums and first seven rows, `Range("A:C")` to select the entire first three columns, `Range("1:3")` to select the entire first three rows, etc. So if you have, say, 14 rows then `Range("D" & j & ":I" & j)` just uses your variable `j` to refer to the ranges "D14:I14", "D13:I13", "D12:I12", etc as you progress through your loop.